# MySQL Workbench can't edit a table that was created using Command Line

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a table in MySQL command line and I'm able to interact with it using python really well. However, I wanted to be able to change values in the table more easily so I installed MySQL workbench to do so.

I have been able to connect to my server but when I try to change any values after selecting a table, it doesn't let me edit it. I tried making a new table within MySQL Workbench and I could edit it then.

So, I started to use that table. However, trying to edit the table python stopped working, so I made another table with command line again and it works!

Does anyone know how to fix either of these problems? It seems MySQL Workbench can only edit tables that have been created with Workbench, and not with Command Line. There must be a configuration option somewhere that is limiting this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Editing a table means to be able to write back data in a way that reliably addresses the records that have changed. In MySQL Workbench there are certain conditions which must be met to make this possible. A result set:

- must have a primary key
- must not have any aggregates or unions
- must not contain subselects

When you do updates in a script you have usually more freedom by writing a WHERE clause that limits changes to a concrete record.